# BigCommerce automatic moxieplayer wrap in tinymce

Tags: bigcommerce

How can I control the behavior of the MCEeditor in the BigCommerce admin control panels?

For instance, I want to add the MCE config `flash_video_player_url: false` per the question [Disabling automatic moxieplayer wrap in tinymce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11429637/disabling-automatic-moxieplayer-wrap-in-tinymce)

I know that I can disable the MCE editor, but I'd like to control it's configuration...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tiny MCE config is within the core BC application and isn't accessible to customize. It would be good to get more info about your use case to see if it's something we could accommodate as a feature request; otherwise, disabling the editor would be the best way to control the content.

Comment: Scenario: Insert HTML 5 video tags without the nested object tag. Already operate with mce disabled when I am doing things because I cant get rid of behaviors I dont want. Feature request, a field that allows entry of a javascript object passed to the editor.